# BSP:R5417: Any SIG_KEY_INFO MUST contain a SECURITY_TOKEN_REFERENCE child element

Tags: cxf, wss4j

The SOAP-server (which I doesn't control) sent me back the answer, which contains the next section:

```
<ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509SubjectName>
            EMAILADDRESS=***@******, CN=*********, OU=***, O=*****, L=****, ST=***, C=**
        </ds:X509SubjectName>
    </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

The specification of [Web Services Security
X.509 Certificate Token Profile 1.1](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13383/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-x509TokenProfile-01.htm) in section 3.2 is saying that `<ds:X509Data>` must be subelement of `<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>`.

Am I watching to right docs and am I right that server sending incorrect response?

Is there are ways to fix this on the client side?

---

p.s. I tried to change WSS4jInInterceptors and set some properties to change key type but I think I did this in incorrect way.

p.p.s And the error stacktrace below:

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: BSP:R5417: Any SIG_KEY_INFO MUST contain a SECURITY_TOKEN_REFERENCE child element
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.createSoapFault(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:809)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:313)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:93)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1636)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1525)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330)
at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215)
at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:638)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:137)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: BSP:R5417: Any SIG_KEY_INFO MUST contain a SECURITY_TOKEN_REFERENCE child element
at org.apache.wss4j.dom.bsp.BSPEnforcer.handleBSPRule(BSPEnforcer.java:57)
at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:158)
at org.apache.wss4j.dom.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:427)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:257)
... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I just removed the WSS4JInInterceptor and developed my custom validator.